# Java BoxLayout gives Incorrect Results

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jpanel, boxlayout

I've got two JPanels that I want to be arranged, one on top of the other, inside of a larger JPanel.  "panel_controls" overrides .getPreferredSize().  Code:

```
public final class GUIPanelMain extends JPanel {
    //...

    private JPanel panel_images;
    private JPanel panel_controls;

    //...

    private void addPanels() {
        new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS); //Bleh!  Still is horizontal!
        this.add(panel_images);
        this.add(panel_controls);
    }

    //...
}
```

Unfortunately, the layout is set up horizontally anyway.  It's only when I resize the JPanel that the components all go in the right places (vertically, in this case).

I read the following in the documentation: "BoxLayout attempts to make all components in the column as wide as the widest component. If that fails, it aligns them horizontally according to their X alignments"

What are the conditions for failure, then?  How can I force it to be vertically aligned?

Thanks,

Comment: You should not be overriding the preferred size of "panel_controls". If you use layout managers properly the layout manager will determine the preferred size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
this.setLayout( new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

You are basically creating a new instance of BoxLayout that goes unused and unreferenced.

Comment: You don't need to put `this` in front of method invocations. It doesn't signify anything.

Comment: @SteveKuo the OP had `this` for other calls. Sometimes it's added for clarity.

Comment: +1, if you don't specifically set the layout manager then a JPanel will use the FlowLayout.

Comment: It doesn't clarify anything as the method could be static, inherited or defined in this class.